# How to constrain union to one given type at runtime?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to be able to create a function factory to update a subpart of a Redux store. In the example below the compiler complains that `state[key]` might be an union. Is there a way to constrain K to be understood as either `"foo"` or `"bar"` at runtime ?

```js
interface State {
  foo: number[];
  bar: string[];
}

const createUpdater = <K extends keyof State>(key: K) => (
  state: State,
  id: number,
  updater: (subState: State[K][number]) => State[K][number]
) => {
  const elements: State[K] = [...state[key]]; // <--- Error
  elements[id] = updater(elements[id]);
  return {
    ...state,
    [key]: elements
  };
};

const fooUpdater = createUpdater("foo");
const barUpdater = createUpdater("bar");
```

Error message:

```
Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'State[K]'.
  Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[] & string[]'.
    Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
      Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAsAKGWRgHsSAuZEAVwFsAjaAbQF0BuAo+uKSgZzBRQAc1Yd8AXwIEEJEAOQIoETBACqABwAmqqMgC8yADwBpZBAAekEFr7IA1hACeJGGgyQAfAApHTyiYAlAaeyN6cyAKqlOiqADQRwFqUNAzQCYTI1Nq6lN581PSxkDEeEEwmLEypjFAswfqhxeWV1XS1LAQNoXiZsvJg5gA2ELQQ4HylqhUsBshMAHRLUZBMfizsyAD0W8YAtAfIAKJQUCRQERAjYxNMSbOG2TqQUN5Xo+NgfHda9eJEyjA1CgIBwESISwWKwgGSIRDWzhYlHeNy+EQk4gx0nw-QUpBImme0DmShUkEJum8ACJ8VTAuJcYNuFAKS8ScpVKzoNTmXTxEA), this is an issue in 3.5.1 but *in 3.6.3 and ES7-beta only in ES3/ES5 targets*: ES2015 and beyond appear to be fine. In both cases K is appropriately constrained as `K extends "foo" | "bar"`. The fact that the target level change causes a type inference error leads me to think this is a bug.

This may be related to [TS 3.5's "Smarter Union Type Checking"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking), but sounds more relevant to [TS 3.6's "More Accurate Array Spread"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-6.html#more-accurate-array-spread), especially given that the generated code in ES5 uses `__spreadArray`.

As a workaround, you could use a type assertion to convince TypeScript that `state[key]` can be duplicated as `State[K]`, but as noted in the "More Accurate Array Spread" section `slice` has slightly different semantics than your spread.

```
const elements = state[key].slice() as State[K];
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! However I'm not able to reproduce it outside the playground. I created a new project with es2015 in target but still have the error. My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true                   
  }
}
```